# AD FS and forms Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, webforms, wif, adfs

We have an Asp.Net website project which uses Forms Authentication. We have been asked to connect to some proxy servers using AD FS to authenticate by one of our clients. I am very new to AD FS and I have a questions.

Authenticate using AD FS is possible only with claims-enabled ASP.NET application or is there a work around to use this with Forms Authentication?

Comment: Is your site claims-aware yet? But even if it's not, you can stick with forms authentication and additionally serve users that logon via sso.

Comment: My site is not claims-aware. I am looking for a method to raise a request  to AD FS proxy and  get an xml response, so that i can parse the xml, read user identify and go ahead with forms authentication. I am not sure about the feasibility of this approach, please guide me.

Comment: Ok. Do you use _ASP.NET Web Forms_ or _ASP.NET MVC_?

Comment: You may refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623136/set-up-sts-but-keep-formsauthentication-in-webapp) quite similar question and the linked [blog post](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-ing-web.html) by Wiktor Zychla. The article was written prior to WIF 4.5 so you may look for the [namespace mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx) (because you'd better use WIF 4.5) and Mike Olson's [blog post](http://azurator.blogspot.de/2013/04/aspnet-mixed-mode-authentication-using.html) taking up on that.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial shows how you can authenticate using ADFS with only a few dozen lines of code.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html

Note the exact moment the SAML token is validated and accepted. In my tutorial I issue the claims identity but you can easily put your forms identity there.

This is because consuming claim/saml token is completely independent of how you later establish a local session.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs. My application is in .Net 3.5, is it possible to configure SAM in this version with the config changes mentioned in your blog?

Comment: My intention is to read a custom attribute value(eg. Employ number) from the saml response and proceed with the current authentication module. Is it possible?

Comment: "// go to STS
 Response.Redirect( req.WriteQueryString() );"                               instead of redirecting to STS, is it possible to pass user name and password from my login page to  AD FS proxy and get saml response. Please excuse me, if i am asking non-scene.

Comment: WIF is flexible and complicated scenarios are possible when you know what to do. Note, that your question doesn't mention .net 3.5 nor custom attributes. This means that you try to ask additional questions in the comment section below an actual answer to your original question. This could lead to a long discussion and could possibly by avoided. Rather, rethink what you really want to ask about and create additional, more specific questions.

Comment: I apologize for asking such a  general question. Now only I got an idea about how it works. I will ask more specific question separately. Please help me.@Wiktor Zychla

Comment: Drop a note here when you ask another question so that I don't miss it.

Comment: This is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655009/configure-wif-for-ad-fs-with-forms-authentication