# Configure WIF for AD FS with forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, adfs

We have an ASP.NET Web Forms(.Net 3.5) website application uses forms authentication. The application has got different customized authentication services which uses different SSO methods(eg. CAS) to validate user, those were implemented for different clients. Now the requirement is to implement an AD FS based authentication service with out making core changes to the Forms Authentication configurations.

My questions:

1. How to configure SAM in .Net 3.5 website
2. Instead of redirecting to STS, is it possible to pass user name and password from my login page to AD FS proxy and get saml response?
3. My intention is to read a custom attribute value(eg. Employ number) from the saml response and proceed with the current authentication module. Is it possible?

This question is based on a discussion in [AD FS and forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650063/ad-fs-and-forms-authentication), any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The snippet I posted as an answer in the previous question should more or less work under .net 3.5 (some apis have changed but not that much so you couldn't figure it out)
2. Although this is possible, I guess this is a bad idea. This is because ADFS could be configured to use some other means of authentication than username/password. For example, they could enable windows integrated authentication. Or they could delegate the authentication to another provider that uses two-factor auth involving text messages. All this means it is more reliable to follow the **passive** ws-fed, where your app redirects to the login page of the provider rather than passing the username/password collected by your app to the provider.
3. The SAML validation in the snipped ends up with the `ClaimsIdentity` that represents the principal from the token. This is where you just enumerate claims and search for the one you want:

   ```
   var identity = .. Validate saml token ..

   foreach ( var claim in identity.Claims )
     if ( claim.Type == employee number claim type )
       Use the claim to establish a local forms auth session
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. The things like SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration, SamlSecurityTokenHandler etc are issuer specific that we need to configure in our code to get a valid token? In other words, other than the url("https://your.sts.address/here"), do we need any other inputs from the issuer?

Comment: Yes, you need the information on issuer's certificate. The certificate is then  matched in the `IssuerNameRegistry` against possible accepted issuers. This is because the `ValidateToken` method must somehow accept/reject SAML tokens based on which certificate is used to sign tokens. Without certificate validation, everyone could issue their own tokens and create valid signatures but using their own certificates.

Comment: Is there any test 'issuer url' from Microsoft or somebody to verify my code?

Comment: issuer's certificate, will it be a file? Do I need to  go for some kind of certificate registration in my server to establish the trust? Please excuse me, if it is an invalid question.

Comment: The example issuer registry is included in my implementation from the previous post. Basically, you supply a method that is invoked and your job is to either accept or reject the certificate. No, it is not a file, it is an object. Look at the `CustomIssuerNameRegistry` from my example.

Comment: From your post, `fam.Issuer = "https://your.sts.address/here";` .Instead of this url, can i have a valid url which can give SAML response? In `CustomIssuerNameRegistry` do i need to verify the `x509Token.Certificate.PublicKey` against the client's public key or what is the correct way to verify the authenticity of the SAML token?

Comment: No, you can't, this is a passive flow which means that the browser redirects there. As for the cert, you for example match the thumbprint to a previously known thumbprint.

Comment: Do you have sample code which matches thumbprint to a previously known thumbprint? Sorry to ask you again, I am very new to this authentication method.

Comment: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-ing-web.html, look for FederatedIssuerNameRegistry. There is nothing wrong in being new but still, there is this free ebook "Claims based identity and Access Control" you just have to read to get not only the overall idea but also, a lot of technical details.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701258/initializepropertiesfromconfigurationstring-servicename-nullreferenceexception ?

Comment: I got this line of code from your atricle `x509Token.Certificate.Thumbprint == WsFederationThumbprint` . I hope this is what you mean by match the thumbprint to a previously known thumbprint. So we need to ask the 'WsFederationThumbprint ' of the issuer. Am i correct? @WiktorZychla

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need to ask for issuer's certificate thumbprint.