# InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(String serviceName) NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, adfs, asp.net-authentication

I have configured 'SessionAuthenticationModule' based on the instructions from http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/forms-authentication-revisited-for-net.html. My application is in .Net 3.5 so I changed the library mappings based on "Namespace Mapping between WIF 3.5 and WIF 4.5". When I run it, it is throwing the exception  shown below.
"

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(String serviceName) +16
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.InitializeModule(HttpApplication context) +124
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.HttpModuleBase.Init(HttpApplication context) +30
```

"
Major configuration settings are shown below.

```
<section name="Microsoft.IdentityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel"/>
    <section name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation"/>
  </configSections>




<Microsoft.IdentityModel></Microsoft.IdentityModel>

<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols>    
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols>
```

Anything wrong with my configurations? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to lack the SAM in `web.config`.

```
  <httpModules>
         <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" 
              type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Take a look at my old tutorial that aims at .NET 3.5

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-ing-web.html

Comment: Do I need to install "Windows Identity Foundation"  from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331 in my machine to run the website? I am facing the run time error : "The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (E:\ADFS_Test\web.config line 44) "

Comment: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions ' is already referred in the application and the reference type is from GAC

Comment: Yes, you need to install the wif 3.5 if you target .net 3.5.

Comment: My development machine is Win 10 and WIF installation is showing "Installer encountered an error: 0x80096002 error". WIF 3.5 is enabled in the Windows Features, but still i am facing the same error...!

Comment: I can't help here. We migrated to .NET 4.5 years ago, WIF is built into it and we never had to install the 3.5 SDK on W10 machines. My advice would be to downgrade to W7 and keep fingers crossed the installer won't complain.

Comment: Two assembly references(Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions) were added automatically to the web.config, when i build it. I have removed those entries hence it's not showing that exception now. Hope it will work with the issuer url. Thank you very much for your continuous support...!