# Configure Microsoft AD FS for use with asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

How can I setup an ADFS subscription option for my asp.net application like the way it's done by Adobe(https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/Configure_Microsoft_AD_FS_for_use_with_Adobe_SSO.html)

I already asked few questions about AD FS integration with Asp.net application. Based on the answer I received from the experts, I need *Issuer url* and *Thumbprint* from the client for the integration. But they are not ready to reveal those information. They need to configure the access to our portal in their AD FS like the way it's working in Adobe Enterprise Dashboard...!

My previous posts about AD FS integration is provided to avoid discussions in that direction. 
[Configure WIF for AD FS with forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655009/configure-wif-for-ad-fs-with-forms-authentication)
[InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(String serviceName) NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701258/initializepropertiesfromconfigurationstring-servicename-nullreferenceexception)
[InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(String serviceName) NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701258/initializepropertiesfromconfigurationstring-servicename-nullreferenceexception)

- How can I create metadata file of my application, that one can add in their AD FS to get subscription to my application?
- I don't know where to start. Someone please give me an overview about doing AD FS integration to asp.net application in the way adobe offers.

Comment: In your previous questions, you appear to be asking how to have your app use an ADFS server to authenticate users of your app.  The link you posted describes how to set up an ADFS server to authenticate adobe users.  So is your question, how do you set up your ADFS server, or is it, how do you set up your application to connect to ADFS?  These are significantly different questions.  [This tutorial](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) might be of use.

Comment: My question is, how I can authenticate the users in my application in the way Adobe is doing. In other words I am not sure how to develop a facility like Abobe provides to give access to my application using AD FS.

Comment: I am waiting for some work around. Please let me now, if anyone need any clarity on my question.

Comment: Did you follow the link I had in my first comment?  It shows both the web app side and ADFS side

Comment: My application is an Asp.net 3.5 website. That article explains the steps to integrate AD FS with MVC application. Please help.

Comment: any help will be much appreciated